# How to do interchangeable armor on character (low poly models)

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, blender

I'm currently working on RPG graphically very similar to Runescape (old school), but with my own game system. I am not sure what is the best way to have interchangeable armor system. I am going to create low poly models, as i said, similar to runescape models like [here](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/runescape2/images/2/2e/Player_avatar.png/revision/latest?cb=20140717195440), and want to have possibility to have random variations of armor like [here](http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140727160541/runescape/images/3/39/Bot_gear_equipped.png).

There are two ways as I understand, first is just to change mesh of my character model, the second one is to create model of my character and use the bones weights to armor models. I know there is whole topic about the first option here (couldn't make 3rd link) *forum.unity3d.com/threads/stitch-multiple-body-parts-into-one-character.16485/*, but really? Every qeustion about something similar leads to this topic. But its like 8 years old and for Unity 2.0...Is there simplier way to achieve same results but don't study masterprompt's exhausting explanation which I'm not gonna be able to implement anyway. And for the second way I can't find any hints, except manual and script on unity web for bone weight, which is way too general for my use and my skills. I have spent looking for some solutions (tutorials) for hours, but google keeps popping the same topics, which are 4-8 years old...

Any advice how to choose the best way for changing armors and how to gain any knowledge about these issues? Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

So what I'm doing in my projects is I duplicate my base character .blend file (rig, model) and I remove most of the mesh except for the body part that I want to make the clothing for (chest/legs). I pull it out a bit so the vertices doesn't overlap with base mesh and just save it.

Then in Unity I create a new prefab out of the model I just saved. The hierarchy of a prefab looks like this: parent game object with BoneReplacer.cs script -> child game object with skinned mesh renderer of my clothing.

Then all I have to do is just drag this prefab onto my character prefab so the target variable in this script points to my character's skinned mesh renderer.

This probably isn't the best way to do this but it works for me, maybe it will help you get your head around it and create some better solution.

Heres the BoneReplacer.cs script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BoneReplacer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject target;
    SkinnedMeshRenderer myRenderer;
    Transform[] newBones;
    SkinnedMeshRenderer targetRenderer;
    Dictionary<string, Transform> boneMap = new Dictionary<string, Transform>();

    void Start()
    {
        target = transform.parent.parent.gameObject;
        targetRenderer = target.GetComponentInChildren<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();

        foreach (Transform _bone in targetRenderer.bones)
        {
            boneMap[_bone.gameObject.name] = _bone;
        }

        myRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
        newBones = new Transform[myRenderer.bones.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < myRenderer.bones.Length; i++)
        {
            GameObject _bone = myRenderer.bones[i].gameObject;
            if (!boneMap.TryGetValue(_bone.name, out newBones[i]))
            {
                Debug.Log("Unable to map bone ~" + _bone.name + "~ to target skeleton!");
                break;
            }
        }

        myRenderer.bones = newBones;
        myRenderer.rootBone = targetRenderer.rootBone;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was going to suggest same approach. You might consider replacing the `break;` with `newBones[i] = _bone.transform;` allowing the attached object to have more bones than the target skeleton. Attached object might have static or procedural animations for those bones which the target skeleton does not (need to) know about.

Comment: Thanks, that's really useful!